Expressing $\frac{2}{n}$ as the sum of two unit fractions
Consider fractions such as $\frac{2}{5}$ and $\frac{2}{7}$ expressed as the sum of two unit fractions. Respectively, they can be expressed as $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{15}$ and $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{28}$.
Generally, $\frac{2}{n}$ can be expressed as $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$  where $\frac{b}{a}=n$ and $a=\frac{n+1}{2}$.
Substituting $a=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and $\frac{b}{a}=n$, it can clearly be seen why this must always be true.
However, I am wondering if there is only one unique way to express an irreducible fraction of the form $\frac{2}{n}$ as the sum of two distinct unit fractions. We have shown $\frac{2}{5}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{15}$, but can this be done any other way.
My attempt at proving this, makes me think there is only one way. However, I cannot complete the proof.
Here is my attempt.
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a+b}{ab}$$
$$2ab=n(a+b)$$
$$b(2a-n)=na$$
$$\frac{b(2a-n)}{a}=n$$
As $n$ and $a$ must both be positive integers $2a-n$ must also be a positive integer and must also be odd, as $ n$ must be odd, by definition of the irreducible fraction, must be coprime with $2$.
So obviously $2a-n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. When $k=0$ we get our intial solution stated at the beginning. However, I cannot seem prove that for other values of $k$ this fails to work, and that the denominators are no longer integers etc.  How can I proceed next?

n>0,a>0 doesn't mean 2a-n>0. Take n=7,a=3

Check if this is of any help: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYiLwPF9pYjICoGaEqfY11RLaHgI43KC/view?usp=drivesdk

For an odd integer $n$, consider the equation $\frac{2}{n} = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$. Then $2ab = na+nb$. This means that $(2a-n)(2b-n)=n^2$.
Notice that $\frac{2}{n} = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}>\frac{1}{a}$ implies $2a-n>0$, and similarly $2b-n>0$.
This means that the $(2a-n)(2b-n)$ is a factorization of $n^2$ as two positive integers.
Now, given $uv=n^2$ any factorization of $n^2$ as two positive integers we can take $2a-n = u$ and $2b-n = v$, so $a=\frac{u+n}{2}$ and $b = \frac{v+n}{2}$ which are positive integers because $u$, $v$ and $n$ are odd.
This means that the solutions to your equation are in bijection with the factorizations of $n^2$, or equivalently, with the positive divisors $u$ of $n^2$.
For example, take $n=15$.
The divisors of $n^2$ are $1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 25, 45, 75, 225$.
This give us the factorizations:
$u\cdot v = 1\cdot 225, 3\cdot 75, 5\cdot 45, 9\cdot 25, 15\cdot 15, 25\cdot 9, 45\cdot 5, 75\cdot 3, 225\cdot 1$
which in turn give us the solutions:
$(a,b) = (8,120),(9,45),(10,30),(12,20),(15,15),(20,12),(30,10),(45,9),(120,8)$
I'm guessing that you are considering the solutions $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ as the same one, and you want $a\ne b$ so we end for this example with the solutions
$(a,b) = (8,120),(9,45),(10,30),(12,20)$
In general, we'll have $\frac{\tau(n^2)-1}{2}$ solutions ($\tau(k)$ is the numbers of positive divisors of $k$).

There are a couple of approaches that you can take - one is called the greedy algorithm:
For the fraction $\frac{x}{y}$ calculate $a=\lceil\frac{y}{x}\rceil$ and then $\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{a}$ to find $\frac{1}{b}$, the second unit fraction.
For example: $\frac{2}{7}$: $a=\lceil\frac{7}{2}\rceil=4$
We then calculate $\frac{2}{7}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{28}$.
Apparently this was developed by Fibonacci some years ago.
For fractions of the form $\frac{2}{p}$ there is the general solution $\frac{2}{p}=\frac{1}{(p+1)/2}+\frac{1}{p(p+1)/2}$
There is also $\frac{2}{pq}=\frac{1}{p(p+q)/2}+\frac{1}{q(p+q)/2}$.
If we have $\frac{2}{35}$ we can use the greedy algorithm to give $\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{630}$ but $\frac{1}{30}+\frac{1}{42}$ is also possible.
So, if $n$ is composite, $\frac{2}{n}$ can be written as a sum of unit fractions in multiple ways. If $n$ is prime...

With your second formula, it would seem that there are as much decomposition as divisors of $n$ strictly greater than $\sqrt n$ from which you substract $1$.

Interesting. I haven't given it that much thought but yes, that makes a lot of sense. I was thinking more of what happens when the fraction is $\frac{2}{p}$ for $p$ prime.

In fact for this case you can prove that the formula above is the only one that works.

Nice. I'll give it some thought.

Eight lines of Python code will immediately answer your question if the representation of $2/n$ as sum of two irreducible unique fractions is unique. The answer is 'No' as the output for $2/9$, $2/15$ and $2/21$ shows.
fractions=[]
for i in range(1,50):
    for j in range(1,i):
        if (2*i*j)%(i+j)==0 and  ((2*i*j)//(i+j))%2!=0:
            fractions.append([(2*i*j)//(i+j),j, i])
fractions.sort()
for f in fractions:
    print("2/%d = 1/%d + 1/%d"%(f[0],f[1],f[2]))

Output:
2/3 = 1/2 + 1/6
2/5 = 1/3 + 1/15
2/7 = 1/4 + 1/28
2/9 = 1/5 + 1/45
2/9 = 1/6 + 1/18
2/15 = 1/9 + 1/45
2/15 = 1/10 + 1/30
2/15 = 1/12 + 1/20
2/21 = 1/14 + 1/42
2/21 = 1/15 + 1/35
2/35 = 1/30 + 1/42


Your program missed the solutions for $2/11$, $2/13$ and one solution for $2/15$

@jjagmath: No, my program didn't even try to find all the solution.  OP's question was if the representation as sum of two irreducible unique fractions is unique and the above output show that the answer is 'No'. I addded this to my answer.

If $2k+1 | n$, $a = \frac{n+2k+1}{2}$ and $b = \frac{n}{2k+1} a$ works. For example $k=1, n=9$ we have $a = 6$ and $b = 18$.
$$
\frac1{6} + \frac1{18}=\frac3{18} + \frac1{18} = \frac29.
$$
So for other values of $k$, this does not fail. In fact we can loosen the condition to $2k+1|n^2$ as $a$ is still an integer and $b = \frac{\frac{n^2}{2k+1} + n}{2}$ as well. For example $k=4, n=15$ ($2k+1 \nmid n$) we have $a = 12$ and $b= 20$.
$$
\frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{20} = \frac{5}{60} + \frac{3}{60} = \frac{2}{15}.
$$

The question asks for sums with $1$ in the numerator.

You should read more carefully what OP and I wrote.
